# The meaning of Classification Accuracy

Tags: classification, random-forest, interpretation, exploratory-data-analysis

I'm working on San Francisco Crime dataset, and only get about 20% classification accuracy. I used Random Forest Method. 
So how I can Interpret the result?
I did EDA firstly, but how can I use EDA to explain the classification?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: we need more details (exact data set, term definition -what is EDA?- etc., formula used for computing accuracy). A minimal reproducible example or at least some sample of your data (input/output) and exact prediction task would help.

Comment: yes, what is EDA? and @Antoine, IIUC, the question is asking the formula itself. to which the answer would be (number of correct classifications) / (number of test samples). Claire, please provide more detail to stop me from speculating :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to decide whether or not you have an adequate model in some sense. Potentially accuracy is not the best measure for you to evaluate your model. If my supposition is correct, maybe re-phrasing to 'what is the best way to evaluate...' is in order, but as Antoine says more details on the task are needed. 
In the mean time, it might be useful to consider that you are trying to improve on random guessing, so if your problem is to classify into five equally likely groups, 20% accuracy represents no improvement, and is a poor model.